# Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV file with lines like this:

```
"AAA", "BBB", "Test, Test", "CCC"
"111", "222, 333", "XXX", "YYY, ZZZ"
```

and so on ...

I dont want to parse comma's under double-quotes. ie. My expected result should be

```
AAA
BBB
Test, Test
CCC
```

My code:

```
import csv
with open('values.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

I tried using csv package under python but no luck. The parses explodes all comma's.

Please let me know if I'm missing something

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This should do:

```
lines = '''"AAA", "BBB", "Test, Test", "CCC"
           "111", "222, 333", "XXX", "YYY, ZZZ"'''.splitlines()
for l in  csv.reader(lines, quotechar='"', delimiter=',',
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
    print l
>>> ['AAA', 'BBB', 'Test, Test', 'CCC']
>>> ['111', '222, 333', 'XXX', 'YYY, ZZZ']
```

Comment: Also, if you have values like these

    _"Test, \"Test\""_

in your CSV, you might also need to add

    _escapechar='\\'_

I just needed it! :)

Comment: This produces a list of length one, which is of no use to anyone who needs to do anything more with these values

Answer (score 23):

You have spaces before the quote characters in your input. Set [`skipinitialspace` to `True`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.skipinitialspace) to skip any whitespace following a delimiter:

> When `True`, whitespace immediately following the *delimiter* is ignored. The default is `False`.

```
>>> import csv
>>> lines = '''\
... "AAA", "BBB", "Test, Test", "CCC"
... "111", "222, 333", "XXX", "YYY, ZZZ" 
... '''
>>> reader = csv.reader(lines.splitlines())
>>> next(reader)
['AAA', ' "BBB"', ' "Test', ' Test"', ' "CCC"']
>>> reader = csv.reader(lines.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True)
>>> next(reader)
['AAA', 'BBB', 'Test, Test', 'CCC']
```

Comment: This helped me, but I don't understand: why (how) does it work?

Comment: I’m not sure what more I can tell you beyond the documentation. There are spaces right after the commas and those are seen as part of the column value unless you set the `skipinitialspace` option to true. And quotes around a value can’t have characters outside of the quotes (or they would not be around the value; when the space after a comma is seen as part of the value then the quoting is also part of the value. By skipping the space the quotes are the outermost parts of the value and are thus handled correctly.

Comment: What do I do, if those initial spaces are BOMs `\ufeff`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: then use the correct codec to open the file. If it's UTF-8, then use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to automatically skip a BOM.

Answer (score 3):

[Posted edited to be more clear.]
If you dont want to parse comma's under double-quotes so your output will include the commas inside the columns, here is another way of doing this. It is elegant and allows you to use cloud buckets to store your CSV file. The key is to use [smart_open](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/1.3.3/) as a drop-in replacement to the standard file open.

Also, I am using [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead of reader.

```
import csv
import json
from smart_open import open

with open('./temp.csv') as csvFileObj:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFileObj, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    # csv.reader requires bytestring input in python2, unicode input in python3
    for record in reader:
        # record is a dictionary of the csv record
        print(f'Record as json shows proper reading of file:\n {json.dumps(record, indent=4)})')
        print(f'You can reference an individual field too: {record["field3"]}')
        print(f'                                           {record["field4"]}')
```

Note that I added 2 parameters to DictReader.
delimiter=',', quotechar='"'
Comma is the default delimiter but I added it in case someone needs to change it.  Quotechar is necessary because it is not the default.
Real output from code:

```
Record as json shows proper reading of file:
 {
    "field1": "AAA",
    "field2": "BBB",
    "field3": "Test, Test",
    "field4": "CCC"
})
You can reference an individual field too: Test, Test
                                           CCC
done
Record as json shows proper reading of file:
 {
    "field1": "111",
    "field2": "222, 333",
    "field3": "XXX",
    "field4": "YYY, ZZZ"
})
You can reference an individual field too: XXX
                                           YYY, ZZZInput file:
```

Input data file (I added a header record for clarity.  If you don't have a header record the first record will get gobbled up but there is prob a parameter for that too.)

```
"field1","field2","field3","field4"
"AAA","BBB","Test, Test","CCC"
"111","222, 333","XXX","YYY, ZZZ"
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @TrentonMcKinney.  I cleaned up the code a little so it is easier to follow what I am doing and provided the output using the original data.  I did have to add the quotechar setting to the original code.  I didn't need it on my data so didn't use it.  I have been using this code for a while now and I am happy with it.