# Python 2.7 read csv file with HTML tags, new lines, double quotes, etc

Tags: html, python-2.7

I have a massive csv file but I just quote an example in here, this is the header's field:

```
"primary_id","follow_up_date","communication_type","content","created_by_user" <<<More fields but you get the idea>>>
```

And this is one of the rows below it

```
12345,NULL,"Email","<p>&nbsp;Hello,</p>
<p>example&nbsp;Hiya.&nbsp;</p>
<p>New York City</p>
<p><strong>Thinking of getting involved in </strong><strong><ahref=\"http://stackoverflow.com/etc/\">Stack Overflow</a> </strong></p>
<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign=\"top\" width=\"73\">&nbsp;</td>
<td valign=\"top\" width=\"378\">
<<<< More here >>>>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
",11,666,129847124,"2015-01-01 11:11:11",0
```

As you can see the content of each value is clearly within the double quote, and if there is a double quote inside, it will be escaped with a "\"

Somehow I just cannot get it to parse correctly, my Python code is :

```
file = request.files['file']
data = file.read()
reader = csv.reader(data,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    print row
```

and the output is:

```
['primary_id', '', '', 'follow_up_date', '', '', 'communication_type', '', '', 'content', '', '', 'created_by_user', '', '', 'etc', '', '', 'etc', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '', '', 'N', 'U', 'L', 'L', '', '', 'Email', '', '', '

Hello,
\r\n

example Hiya. 
\r\n

New York City
\r\n

Thinking of getting involved in Stack Overflow
\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
\r\n<<<< More here >>>>\r\n
\r\n', '', '', '1', '1', '', '', '6', '6', '6', '', '', '1', '2', '9', '8', '4', '7', '1', '2', '4', '', '', '2015-01-01 11:11:11', '', '', '0']
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes