# csv ignore comma inside double quote

Tags: python, csv

```
"Medical Center Emergency Physicians \"North Shore\"  Houston, TX  EM  MD-DO",2680,18882
```

I want it to be read in as length 3 list use python csv module this my expected output

`["Medical Center Emergency Physicians \"North Shore\"  Houston, TX  EM  MD-DO", 
'2680', 
18882]`

I have tried a lot use different parameter. But all the below I tried doesn't work for me. All of them output a length 4 list. I think this is caused by the comma after Huston. But how can we ignore it since it is in a double quote?

```
csv_reader = csv.reader(f, doublequote=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
csv_reader = csv.reader(f, doublequote=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
csv_reader = csv.reader(f, doublequote=False)
csv_reader = csv.reader(f, doublequote=True)
csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes)

Comment: @mkrieger1 - the problem is the escaped quotes. Your proposed duplicate doesn't work for this.

Comment: Actually the problem here is a little bit different than in the linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an escape character to deal with escaped quotes in the csv

```
csv.reader(f, doublequote=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, escapechar='\\')
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use:

```
csv.reader(f, quotechar='"')
```

and possibly some parameter to tell the reader the quotes are escaped with `\`. But if your current output is 4 fields, it seems to split on the `,`, ignoring the `\"`.

Most likely like this:

```
csv.reader(f, quotechar='"', escapechar='\\')
```

Those `\` shouldn't be in your output (unless you need them for further processing).