# CSV file has commas in data, which python interprets as extra columns

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I have a CSV with commas in two of the cells. The cells are marked with quotations.

e.g `"1","METHOD - Standard","NGSG 01 MIDLAND FAB","GALINDO-REG, MARISOL",`

When I try to import the CSV file using the line:

```
csv = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',',dtype=str)
```

Python gives an error, saying that the rows have different numbers of columns.

The data in cell has to remain the same, and I have to remove the quotations, since the array will later be imported into a different program.

I need a way to keep the comma in the data, without starting a new column. How can I achieve this?

Edit:
This question was marked as a possible duplicate. The answer to the other question was:

```
lines = '''"AAA", "BBB", "Test, Test", "CCC"
           "111", "222, 333", "XXX", "YYY, ZZZ"'''.splitlines()
for l in  csv.reader(lines, quotechar='"', delimiter=',',
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
    print l
```

This looks like it would work, but -

1, How do I read from a file, instead of a variable?

2, How do I make an array out of the reader object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

So if you want to convert your file into a list of lists:

```
 import csv

 myFileAsArray = []
 with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
   spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
   for row in spamreader:
     myFileAsArray.append(row)
```

Comment: That works, but it just prints the file. I was using `csv = np.genfromtxt(filename, delimiter=',',dtype=str)` to convert the file into an array, so that I could reference the values later; e.g. `csv[19,17]` How would I save the rows to an array, instead of just printing them?

Comment: in the example, `row` is a list of String, representing a line of the CSV file. See my edit if it helps.