# Removing quotes from text files

Tags: python

I need to read a pipe(|)-separated text file.
One of the fields contains a description that may contain double-quotes.
I noticed that all lines that contain a " is missing in the receiving dict.
To avoid this, I tried to read the entire line, and use the string.replace() to remove them, as shown below, but it looks like the presence of those quotes creates problem at the line-reading stage, i.e before the string.replace() method.

The code is below, and the question is 'how to force python not to use any separator and keep the line whole ?".

```
with open(fileIn) as txtextract:
    readlines = csv.reader(txtextract,delimiter="µ")
    for line in readlines:
        (...)
        LI_text = newline[107:155]
        LI_text.replace("|","/")
        LI_text.replace("\"","") # use of escape char don't work.
```

Note: I am using version 3.6

Comment: `replace` does not replace in place. You must assign the result back to the variable: `LI_text = LI_text.replace("|","/")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes)

Comment: That was due to the "replace in place" issue. I stored the modified text back in the variable and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use regex

```
    In [1]: import re

    In [2]: re.sub(r"\"", "", '"remove all "double quotes" from text"')
    Out[2]: 'remove all double quotes from text'

    In [3]: re.sub(r"(^\"|\"$)", "", '"remove all "only surrounding quotes" from text"')
    Out[3]: 'remove all "only surrounding quotes" from text'
```

or add `quote='"'` and `quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL` options to `csv.reader()`, like:

```
    with open(fileIn) as txtextract:
        readlines = csv.reader(txtextract, delimiter="µ", quote='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for line in readlines:
            (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lesson: method string.replace() does not change the string itself. The modified text must be stored back (string = string.replace() )