# read space delimited CSV with quoted values

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have a shell command that return rows like

```
timestamp=1511270820724797892 eventID=1511270820724797892 eventName="corvil_request_summary" channelID="HTTP: Other" channelDir=false classID="class-default" packetID=2809419165205232 messageOffset=1 warnCSMInvalidSample=false warnCSMOverflow=false warnEventInvalidSample=false Server="nginx/1.10.1" Method="GET" RequestURI="/system/varlogmessages/" UserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0" WebSite="backup-server-new" Domain="backup-server-new" SrcIP="172.20.1.13" SrcPort="80" DstIP="172.18.4.181" DstPort="60065" 

timestamp=1511270820735795372 eventID=1511270820735795372 eventName="corvil_request_summary" channelID="HTTP: Other" channelDir=false classID="class-default" packetID=2809419176202992 messageOffset=1 warnCSMInvalidSample=false warnCSMOverflow=false warnEventInvalidSample=false Server="probe" Method="GET" RequestURI="/system/status" WebSite="probe609:8111" Domain="probe609:8111" SrcIP="172.20.2.109" SrcPort="8111" DstIP="172.18.4.96" DstPort="49714"
```

I am trying to read it as:

```
for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(execute(cmd), delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)):                                                                                                                           
    print i, len(row)                                                                                                                                                                                              
    if i > 10:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        break
```

but this is not working correctly as white spaces inside quotes are not ignored. For example `channelID="HTTP: Other"` is split as two variables because of the space between `HTTP:` and `Other`

What is the right way to parse this type of input?

Comment: Have you tried `quotechar='"'`?

Comment: My current solution is:  `row = {k:v.strip('"') for k,v in re.findall(r'(\S+)=(".*?"|\S+)', row)}`

Comment: I have just realised that the current solution does not work in some cases

Comment: @Donbeo which ones?

Comment: The one in the comment above

Comment: Can't see which rows may let your regex not match correctly. Your solution works like a charm with the example lines you've posted.

Comment: it was breaking with some weird `RequestURI`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hackish, but it strikes me that the rules here are similar to those for parsing attributes in an HTML tag.

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
#from html.parser import HTMLParser     # Python 3

# Create a parser that simply dumps the tag attributes to an instance variable    
class AttrParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.attrs = attrs

# Our input
to_parse = 'channelID="HTTP: Other" channelDir=false classID="class-default"'

# Create a parser instance
parser = AttrParser()
# Wrap our input text inside a dummy HTML tag and feed it into the parser
parser.feed('<NOTAG {}>'.format(to_parse))
# Read the results
print(parser.attrs)
```

Result:

```
[('channelid', 'HTTP: Other'), 
 ('channeldir', 'false'), 
 ('classid', 'class-default')]
```

Comment: this seems to be working. The only downside is that it makes all lowercase

Answer (score 0):

Regex to find keys then use keys for offsets

```
lines = [
    '''timestamp=1511270820724797892 eventID=1511270820724797892 eventName="corvil_request_summary" channelID="HTTP: Other" channelDir=false classID="class-default" packetID=2809419165205232 messageOffset=1 warnCSMInvalidSample=false warnCSMOverflow=false warnEventInvalidSample=false Server="nginx/1.10.1" Method="GET" RequestURI="/system/varlogmessages/" UserAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0" WebSite="backup-server-new" Domain="backup-server-new" SrcIP="172.20.1.13" SrcPort="80" DstIP="172.18.4.181" DstPort="60065"''',
    '''timestamp=1511270820735795372 eventID=1511270820735795372 eventName="corvil_request_summary" channelID="HTTP: Other" channelDir=false classID="class-default" packetID=2809419176202992 messageOffset=1 warnCSMInvalidSample=false warnCSMOverflow=false warnEventInvalidSample=false Server="probe" Method="GET" RequestURI="/system/status" WebSite="probe609:8111" Domain="probe609:8111" SrcIP="172.20.2.109" SrcPort="8111" DstIP="172.18.4.96" DstPort="49714"''',
]
results = []
for line in lines:
    result = {}
    keys = re.findall(r'\w+=', line)
    for idx, k in enumerate(keys):
        start = line.find(k)
        if idx + 1 >= len(keys):
            end = len(line)
        else:
            end = line.find(keys[idx+1])
        key, value = line[start:end].strip().split("=")
        if isinstance(value, str):
            if value.lower() == "true":
                value = True
            elif value.lower() == "false":
                value = False
            elif value.isdigit():
                value = int(value)
            else:
                value = value.strip('"')
        result[key] = value
    results.append(result)
```