# How to parse csv with quoted strings - advanced case

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to make csv module to parse lines containing quoted strings and quoted separators. Unfortunately I'm not able to achieve desired results with any dialect/format parameters. Is there any way to parse this:

```
'"AAA", BBB, "CCC, CCC"'
```

and get this:

```
['"AAA"', 'BBB', '"CCC, CCC"']    # 3 elements, one quoted separator
```

?

Two fundamental requirements:

1. Quotations have to be preserved
2. Quoted, and not escaped separators have to be copied as regular characters

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 issues to overcome:

- spaces around comma separator: `skipinitialspace=True` does the job (see also [Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes))
- preserving quoting *when reading*: replacing quotes by tripled quotes allows to preserve quotes

That second part is described in the documentation as:

> Dialect.doublequote
>
> Controls how instances of quotechar appearing inside a field should themselves be quoted. **When True, the character is doubled**. When False, the escapechar is used as a prefix to the quotechar. **It defaults to True.**

standalone example, without file:

```
import csv
data = ['"AAA", BBB, "CCC, CCC"'.replace('"','"""')]

cr = csv.reader(data,skipinitialspace=True)
row = next(cr)
print(row)
```

result:

```
['"AAA"', 'BBB', '"CCC, CCC"']
```

with a file as input:

```
import csv
with open("input.csv") as f:
  cr = csv.reader((l.replace('"','"""' for l in f),skipinitialspace=True)
  for row in cr:
     print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
import csv
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print row
```