# How to replace any alphanumeric data in a column with 0 with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Im new with pandas and trying to find the mean of the average BasePay from Salaries.csv file downloaded from [kaggle.com](https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle/sf-salaries) "SF Salaries". But the extra commas occuring ","
 in the JobTitle field (for example ID 5) seems to create problem since default field separator is ",".

```
Id,EmployeeName,JobTitle,BasePay,OvertimePay,OtherPay,Benefits,TotalPay,TotalPayBenefits,Year,Notes,Agency,Status
1,NATHANIEL FORD,GENERAL MANAGER-METROPOLITAN TRANSIT AUTHORITY,167411.18,0.0,400184.25,,567595.43,567595.43,2011,,San Francisco,
2,GARY JIMENEZ,CAPTAIN III (POLICE DEPARTMENT),155966.02,245131.88,137811.38,,538909.28,538909.28,2011,,San Francisco,
3,ALBERT PARDINI,CAPTAIN III (POLICE DEPARTMENT),212739.13,106088.18,16452.6,,335279.91,335279.91,2011,,San Francisco,
4,CHRISTOPHER CHONG,WIRE ROPE CABLE MAINTENANCE MECHANIC,77916.0,56120.71,198306.9,,332343.61,332343.61,2011,,San Francisco,
5,PATRICK GARDNER,"DEPUTY CHIEF OF DEPARTMENT,(FIRE DEPARTMENT)",134401.6,9737.0,182234.59,,326373.19,326373.19,2011,,San Francisco,
```

One way i currently see is by editing file replacing comma with whitespace or "|" with sed

```
sed 's/\(\"[^",]\{1,\}\),\([^",]\{1,\}\"\)/\1 | \2/g'
```

and use

```
sal=pd.read_csv('/Users/Downloads/Salaries.csv')
sal['BasePay'].mean()
```

Are there any other ways provided by pandas to clean such data ?

Comment: maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/21527375/9754169

Comment: i think you just need to specify that the quote character (`quotechar`) is `"`, which _should_ be the default anyway for `read_csv`

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: @HaleemurAli sal=pd.read_csv('/Users/ezer/Downloads/test.csv',skipinitialspace = True, quotechar = '"')..i tried without  skipinitialspace but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

**Using small function to eradicate the unwanted comma's in the field**

```
data = pd.read_csv("Salaries.csv")
data.head()
def remove_comma(text):
   text = "".join([filtered_text for filtered_text in text if filtered_text != ","])
   return text

data["JobTitle"] = data["JobTitle"].apply(lambda x: remove_comma(x))
```

as the BasePay column in the dataset holds string values, its preferred to replace "Not provided" values into 0.00 and convert into float for the mean operation

```
data["BasePay"] = data["BasePay"].replace("Not Provided","0.00").astype("float64")
data["BasePay"].mean()
```