# pyspark-java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm running pyspark-sql code on Horton sandbox

**18/08/11 17:02:22 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.3**

```
# code 
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
rdd1 = sc.textFile ("/user/maria_dev/spark_data/products.csv")
rdd2 = rdd1.map( lambda x : x.split("," ) )
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd2, ["id","cat_id","name","desc","price", "url"])
df1.printSchema()

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cat_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: string (nullable = true)
 |-- url: string (nullable = true)

df1.show() 
+---+------+--------------------+----+------+--------------------+
| id|cat_id|                name|desc| price|                 url|
+---+------+--------------------+----+------+--------------------+
|  1|     2|Quest Q64 10 FT. ...|    | 59.98|http://images.acm...|
|  2|     2|Under Armour Men'...|    |129.99|http://images.acm...|
|  3|     2|Under Armour Men'...|    | 89.99|http://images.acm...|
|  4|     2|Under Armour Men'...|    | 89.99|http://images.acm...|
|  5|     2|Riddell Youth Rev...|    |199.99|http://images.acm...|

# When I try to get counts I get the following error.
df1.count()

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 6 fields are required while 7 values are provided.**

# I get the same error for the following code as well
df1.registerTempTable("products_tab")
df_query = sqlContext.sql ("select id, name, desc from products_tab order by name, id ").show();
```

I see column desc is null, not sure if null column needs to be handled differently when creating data frame and using any method on it.

The same error occurs when running sql query. It seems sql error is due to "order by" clause, if I remove order by then query runs successfully.

Please let me know if you need more info and appreciate answer on how to handle this error.

I tried to see if name field contains any comma, as suggested by Chandan Ray.
There's no comma in name field.

```
rdd1.count()
=> 1345
rdd2.count()
=> 1345
# clipping id and name column from rdd2
rdd_name = rdd2.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[2]) )
rdd_name.count()
=>1345
rdd_name_comma = rdd_name.filter (lambda x : True if x[1].find(",") != -1  else False )
rdd_name_comma.count()
==> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue- it was due to one bad record, where comma was embedded in string. And even though string was double quoted, python splits string into 2 columns.
I tried using databricks package

```
# from command prompt
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0

# on pyspark 
 schema1 = StructType ([ StructField("id",IntegerType(), True), \
         StructField("cat_id",IntegerType(), True), \
         StructField("name",StringType(), True),\
         StructField("desc",StringType(), True),\
         StructField("price",DecimalType(), True), \
         StructField("url",StringType(), True)
         ])

df1 = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').schema(schema1).load('/user/maria_dev/spark_data/products.csv')
        df1.show()
df1.show()
    +---+------+--------------------+----+-----+--------------------+
    | id|cat_id|                name|desc|price|                 url|
    +---+------+--------------------+----+-----+--------------------+
    |  1|     2|Quest Q64 10 FT. ...|    |   60|http://images.acm...|
    |  2|     2|Under Armour Men'...|    |  130|http://images.acm...|
    |  3|     2|Under Armour Men'...|    |   90|http://images.acm...|
    |  4|     2|Under Armour Men'...|    |   90|http://images.acm...|
    |  5|     2|Riddell Youth Rev...|    |  200|http://images.acm...|

df1.printSchema()
    root
     |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- cat_id: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- name: string (nullable = true)
     |-- desc: string (nullable = true)
     |-- price: decimal(10,0) (nullable = true)
     |-- url: string (nullable = true)

df1.count()
     1345
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your name field has comma in it, so its splitting this also. So its expecting 7 columns

There might be some malformed lines.

Please try to use the code as below to exclude bad record in one file

```
val df = spark.read.format(“csv”).option("badRecordsPath", "/tmp/badRecordsPath").load(“csvpath”)
```

//it will read csv and create a dataframe, if there will be any malformed record it will move this into the path you provided.

// please read below

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/handling-bad-records.html

Comment: Thanks Chandan for looking into my question. I dont see any comma in name field. Please see my original post, I've added code to check comma in name field.

Comment: Please provide few sample lines of your data

Comment: Thanks Chandan, it was data issue. Found it hard way .. :)

Comment: But you can use the above answer to filter out the malformed data. Please use it and check

Comment: Chandan, I'm using spark 1.6.3 and I tried to use the code similar to one provided by you. It results into error : : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org . I guess "csv" format is not available in 1.6.3. I used csv solution by using databricks package as mentioned in my post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That’s correct the option might not be supported in the 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on cleaning of such records, we normally encounter such situations:

a. Anomaly on the data where the file when created, was not looked if "," is the best delimiter on the columns.

Here is my solution on the case:

Solution a: In such cases, we would like to have the process identify as part of data cleansing if that record is a qualified records. The rest of the records if routed to a bad file/collection would give the opportunity to reconcile such records.

Below is the structure of my dataset (product_id,product_name,unit_price)

```
1,product-1,10
2,product-2,20
3,product,3,30
```

In the above case, product,3 is supposed to be read as product-3 which might have been a typo when the product was registered. In such as case, the below sample would work.

```
>>> tf=open("C:/users/ip2134/pyspark_practice/test_file.txt")
>>> trec=tf.read().splitlines()
>>> for rec in trec:
...   if rec.count(",") == 2:
...      trec_clean.append(rec)
...   else:
...      trec_bad.append(rec)
...
>>> trec_clean
['1,product-1,10', '2,product-2,20']
>>> trec_bad
['3,product,3,30']
>>> trec
['1,product-1,10', '2,product-2,20','3,product,3,30']
```

The other alternative of dealing with this problem would be trying to see if skipinitialspace=True would work to parse out the columns.

(Ref:[Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes))

Comment: Thanks Himansu. The solution you provided is clean and easy to follow. The only issue here i see is - few records where comma is embeded in double quotes would be dropped from processing. When I use databricks package it works as expected ie considers comma without quotes as separator.