# Pyspark toDF() Throw IllegalStateException Using collect()

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I am using BeautifulSoup and Pyspark to crawl the web. I have a test csv file containing 20 links that I want to extract links within the websites.

```
links = spark.read.text("top-20.csv")
b = links.rdd.map(lambda link: crawl(link,depth))
```

The crawl function returns a list containing 267 elements. If the line had toDF() at the end.

```
b = links.rdd.map(lambda link: crawl(link,depth)).toDF()
```

Then using the line.

```
output = b.collect()
```

The function throws

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 20 fields are required while 267 values are provided.
```

I don't understand why it throws the exception using toDF(). Why is it still expecting 20 rows when the new value is 267 rows? The conversion from rdd to df is obviously not necessary but I am interested in how it works.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247386/pyspark-java-lang-illegalstateexception-input-row-doesnt-have-expected-number,

Comment: I see, I think I understand the reason thank you.