# How to skip comma while reading CSV file in python?

Tags: python, list, csv, delimiter, reader

I am reading a column of csv file using reader method. One of my column contains string value with comma in it. But reader is reading it as a two different value when I use delimiter as comma.

My requirement is, code should read this column value as a single string only and reader method should use delimiter as a comma only.

**Input** : 
        "11"11","Bob Marley, USA","ABC"

**Code** :

```
reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")
output = []
for row in reader:
    output = list(row)
    for each in output:
        print(each)
```

**Output**:

```
"11"11"
"Bob Marley
 USA"
"ABC"
```

**Desired output:**
 "1111" "Bob Marley USA" "ABC"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `quotechar="'"` should be `quotechar='"'`, since the input uses `"` for String values.

**Edit 1:**

You cannot use control characters inside the cells without escaping them, so your input needs to escape each `"` inside a cell. Otherwise it will break.

The following code will work for `"11\"11","Bob Marley, USA","ABC"`, but not `"11"11","Bob Marley, USA","ABC"`:

```
reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', escapechar='\\', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    for cell in row:
        print cell
```

You might be able to replace the `"` with `\"` with a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Comment: Ok. But if we get the double quote also in string value then it's not gonna work anymore. This is a bug in csv file and I have to write a code to deal with it.

Comment: In that case, you need to escape those quotemarks with a backslash and add `escapechar='\\'` to the reader's options. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21527375/10761013)

Comment: I updated my answer. The CSV reader will not be able to handle your current input the way you desire. You have to clean the input in another way beforehand.