# How separate items based on single quote charcters - i.e. ['a','b','x,d'] => a b 'x,d'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am parsing a csv file and extracting all the data and separating them out based on quotes.
For simplicity, I am taking a random line from that file

Input:

```
line = "'abc', 'sxy', 'lmo,por','zz'"
```

Output Desired:

```
abc
sxy
'lmo,por'
zz
```

Line 3 in the desired output is where I am getting suck with the code. If I do a replace("'","") then I lose all the quotes and get separated out.
I am not sure how I can club the line 3 values as such without losing the single quote while I need to strip single quote for other's
Is there a python inbuilt string function for this.

I am not sure who can I write a regex as I am pretty new to regex parsing.

My code so far:

```
line = "'abc', 'sxy', 'lmo,por','zz'"

def parse(line):
    line = line.replace("'","")
    a = line.split(',')
    for word in a:
        l.append(word)
    print(l)
```

I know this is very trivial, but i cannot get a work around for it. SO also does not have similar situation.
Appreciate any pointers that could help me out.

Comment: So you want to remove single quotes in all cases except when there's a comma in between?

Comment: Can you rely on the presence of a space after the commas that separate the strings? e.g. there is a space after the comma after `'abc', ` but not between `lmo` and `por`

Comment: @puskin yes I need to remove the quote all except when there is a comma in between

Comment: csv module might take care of it

Comment: @CharlieWindolf I cannot rely on space since the source file is generated bya third party tool and there could potentially be issues with the file (The space my not be consistent)

Comment: @balki can you please explain which csv module ? Is there a separate one in python apart from regular csv ?

Comment: The [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) `csv` module is very powerful, and contains a nice reader and writer interface which will all of your needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes)

Answer (score 4):

The python `csv` package features a `quotechar` parameter, which I think will fit your needs. As a general rule-of-thumb, do not wrestle with `csv` document by parsing everything yourself, and *do not* use Regular Expressions.

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and a [relative discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes)

This should do the trick (I suppose you'll have to parse multiple lines).

```py
lines = """ 'abc', 'sxy', 'lmo,por','zz'
'some,thing', 'some', thing""".splitlines()

for l in  csv.reader(lines, quotechar="'", delimiter=',', 
                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True):
    print(l)

# ['abc', 'sxy', 'lmo,por', 'zz']
# ['some,thing', 'some', 'thing']
```

Comment: I updated the code with a complete example, this should work as you need. It will split the lines on every comma, *but not* on commas which are quoted by `quotechar`.

Comment: If you really need to preserve the `'` in the values that contain a `,` then you can loop over the values in `l`, and quote any that contain `,`. This is still better than using a regex to parse the input IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple one:

`line = "'abc', 'sxy', 'lmo,por','zz'"`

```
def parse(line):
    li = []
    lines = line.split("',")
    for line in lines:
        word = line.replace("'", "").strip()
        print (word)
        li.append(word)
    return li
```

First split by ', and after removed all white spaces and single quote

Comment: the above solution will work if you have consistent ', in your file. If there is a data issue and there are single quotes missing, then you solution will not cover those cases.

Comment: This solves the OP. One cannot take into account the unlimited amount of possible errors in the data file.