# Commas in column values of Comma separate value file - python read issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am loading a comma separate file into python and loading into SQL Server table.
But facing an issue while reading Company column.
Reason: ., special characters in Company column values. 
So that my python code reading two columns for Company values XYZ Co., Ltd,YZA Co., Ltd and XYZ Co., Ltd

How to fix this issue?
**Source data in CSV:**

```
ID,Company,Date,Sales
1,ABC Company Ltd,10-Jun-19,10
2,BCD Company Ltd,11-Jun-19,20
3,XYZ Co., Ltd,12-Jun-19,30
4,YZA Co., Ltd,13-Jun-19,40
5,CDF Company Ltd,14-Jun-19,50
6,XYZ Co., Ltd,15-Jun-19,60
7,ABC Company Ltd,16-Jun-19,70
8,ABC Company Ltd,17-Jun-19,80
```

**Expected out from python Pandas:**
[image]

Comment: Data which might contain 'comma' in the text should be inside quotes for proper parsing. If that's possible in your case: follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pandas.read_csv` with `escapechar`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/your/file', sep = ",",escapechar='.')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   ID          Company       Date  Sales
0   1  ABC Company Ltd  10-Jun-19     10
1   2  BCD Company Ltd  11-Jun-19     20
2   3      XYZ Co, Ltd  12-Jun-19     30
3   4      YZA Co, Ltd  13-Jun-19     40
4   5  CDF Company Ltd  14-Jun-19     50
5   6      XYZ Co, Ltd  15-Jun-19     60
6   7  ABC Company Ltd  16-Jun-19     70
7   8  ABC Company Ltd  17-Jun-19     80
```

If you want your `.` back, do manual replacement after reading it:

```
df['Company'] = df['Company'].replace('Co,', 'Co.,', regex=True)
```

Output:

```
   ID          Company       Date  Sales
0   1  ABC Company Ltd  10-Jun-19     10
1   2  BCD Company Ltd  11-Jun-19     20
2   3     XYZ Co., Ltd  12-Jun-19     30
3   4     YZA Co., Ltd  13-Jun-19     40
4   5  CDF Company Ltd  14-Jun-19     50
5   6     XYZ Co., Ltd  15-Jun-19     60
6   7  ABC Company Ltd  16-Jun-19     70
7   8  ABC Company Ltd  17-Jun-19     80
```