# Inconsistent quotes on .csv file

Tags: python, csv, qualifiers

I have a comma delimited file which also contains commas in the actual field values, something like this:

```
foo,bar,"foo, bar"
```

This file is very large so I am wondering if there is a way in python to either put double quotes around ever field:

```
eg: "foo","bar","foo, bar"
```

or just change the delimeter overall?

```
eg: foo|bar|foo, bar
```

End goal:
The goal is to ultimately load this file into sql server. Given the size of the file bulk insert is only feasible approach for loading but I cannot specify a text qualifier/field quote due to the version of ssms I have.

This leads me to believe the only remaining approach is to do some preprocessing on the source file.

Comment: I'm sure either could be done with Python.

Comment: csv.reader has a [quote character](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) parameter. If you specify `quotechar='"'` it should treat `"foo,bar"` as a single column.

Comment: Why do you care about inconsistent quoting? Your file is only using them where necessary; adding more just bloats the file size.

Comment: the goal is to ultimately load this file into sql server. Given the size of the file bulk insert is only feasible approach for loading but I cannot specify a text qualifier/field quote due to the version of ssms I have.

Comment: Does [Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the delimiter just requires parsing and re-encoding the data.

```
with open("data.csv") as input, open("new_data.csv", "w") as output:
    r = csv.reader(input, delimiter=",", quotechar='"')
    w = csv.writer(output, delimiter="|")
    w.writerows(r)
```

Given that your input file is a fairly standard version of CSV, you don't even need to specify the delimiter and quote arguments to `reader`; the defaults will suffice.

```
r = csv.reader(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not an inconsistent quotes. If a value in a CSV file has comma or new line in it quotes are added to it. It shoudn't be a problem, because all standard CSV readers can read it properly.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the inconsistency of not quoting *every* field, only those that require quoting.