# How to convert csv file into json in python so that the header of csv are keys of every json value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I have this use case

please create a function called “myfunccsvtojson” that takes in a filename path to a csv file (please refer to attached csv file) and generates a file that contains streamable line delimited JSON.

•   Expected filename will be based on the csv filename, i.e. Myfilename.csv will produce Myfilename.json or File2.csv will produce File2.json. Please show this in your code and should not be hardcoded.

•   csv file has 10000 lines including the header

•   output JSON file should contain 9999 lines

•   Sample JSON lines from the csv file below:

CSV:

```
nconst,primaryName,birthYear,deathYear,primaryProfession,knownForTitles
nm0000001,Fred Astaire,1899,1987,"soundtrack,actor,miscellaneous","tt0072308,tt0043044,tt0050419,tt0053137" nm0000002,Lauren Bacall,1924,2014,"actress,soundtrack","tt0071877,tt0038355,tt0117057,tt0037382" nm0000003,Brigitte Bardot,1934,\N,"actress,soundtrack,producer","tt0057345,tt0059956,tt0049189,tt0054452"
```

JSON lines:

```
{"nconst":"nm0000001","primaryName":"Fred Astaire","birthYear":1899,"deathYear":1987,"primaryProfession":"soundtrack,actor,miscellaneous","knownForTitles":"tt0072308,tt0043044,tt0050419,tt0053137"}
{"nconst":"nm0000002","primaryName":"Lauren Bacall","birthYear":1924,"deathYear":2014,"primaryProfession":"actress,soundtrack","knownForTitles":"tt0071877,tt0038355,tt0117057,tt0037382"}
{"nconst":"nm0000003","primaryName":"Brigitte Bardot","birthYear":1934,"deathYear":null,"primaryProfession":"actress,soundtrack,producer","knownForTitles":"tt0057345,tt0059956,tt0049189,tt0054452"}
```

I am not able to understand is how the header can be inputted as a key to every value of jason.

Has anyone come access this scenario and help me out of it?

What i was trying i know loop is not correct but figuring it out

```
with open(file_name, encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
    csv_data = csv.DictReader(file)
    csvreader = csv.reader(file)
    # print(csv_data)
    keys = next(csvreader)
    print (keys)
    for i,Value in range(len(keys)), csv_data:
        data[keys[i]] = Value
        print (data)
```

Comment: What have you tried and what particular problem you are unable to solve? Have you ever heard of `csv.DictReader`?

Comment: Take the first row as list of headers and create a dict for every row after the header row and load the whole thing as json.

Comment: One tricky issue is your CSV file uses commas as delimiters but is ignored in double quotes.  On how to handle this check out [Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes) on how to

Comment: @buran i have i tried it, but didnt seem to work with this use case

Comment: Then, show what have you tried.

Comment: @buran have added it in the question

Comment: You create 2 readers - one `csv.reader` (that is `csvreader`) and one `csv.DictReader` (that is `csv_data`). Just create a `csv.DictReader` and use it. Then, this `for i,Value in range(len(keys)), csv_data:` really doesn't make sense. And `data` is not defined at all. Just iterate over `csv_data` (it will yield a `dict`) and write that dict to your output file.

Comment: @buran like i told i was trying something with the loop. 
DictReader doesnt work with this use case. 
or unless you have some thing to show the way it can implemented

Comment: pont is my header for CSV should be the key for all the records

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader): Create an object that operates like a regular reader but **maps the information in each row to a dict whose keys are given by the optional fieldnames parameter.**

The fieldnames parameter is a sequence. **If fieldnames is omitted, the values in the first row of file f will be used as the fieldnames.**

Comment: @Devendrakumarsingh alredy showed a solution, but he produce JSON array, not `ndjson`. However the `csv.DictPart` is right.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your csv to pandas data frame and output as json:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.to_json(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import json
 
def csv_to_json(csv_file_path, json_file_path):
    data_dict = []
    with open(csv_file_path, encoding = 'utf-8') as csv_file_handler:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file_handler)
        for rows in csv_reader:
            data_dict.append(rows)
    with open(json_file_path, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as json_file_handler:
        json_file_handler.write(json.dumps(data_dict, indent = 4))
csv_to_json("/home/devendra/Videos/stackoverflow/Names.csv", "/home/devendra/Videos/stackoverflow/Names.json")
```

Comment: Note that OP wants to produce `ndjson`/`json lines`

Comment: @buran doesnt product a proper output

Comment: @sumanthshetty, if it does not produce the expected result, then check your input file. Probably there is problem with that file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).