# Python import csv file with commas and double-quotes

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to import a csv file whose separators are commas, however I do not want to parse commas under double quotes:

```
region,votes,share,liste
1,1453,"45,16",ABC
2,5489,"54,17","BCD,DEF"
3,5486,32,WSE
```

Dataframe that I want

```
region votes share liste
1      1453  45.16 ABC
2      5489  54.17 BCD DEF
3      5486  32    WSE
```

I tried the following code, considering the previous question [Python parse CSV ignoring comma with double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes) :

```
df=csvReader(myfile, quotechar='"', delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, skipinitialspace=True)
```

but I receive the following message:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

How can I properly import this dataset?

Comment: Where I can find the value of ```\UXXXXXX```?

Comment: By any chance, is `myfile` a windows path like `c:\foo.csv` that might need escaping like `c:\\foo.csv` or better yet `c:/foo.csv`?

Comment: If I write a windows path like ```c:/foo.csv```, the code runs, but the dataframe becomes ```<csv.DictReader at 0x143e8d07490>```

Comment: Get all the rows via `df = list(df)` to read all the rows at once from the reader. Note that this is not a pandas dataframe at this point and that pandas has a `read_csv()` method.

Comment: You are not working with a Pandas DataFrame you are working with an iterator for the Python [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module. You need to pay attention to the code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), a very basic approach will be to set the (`,`) as the character to be recognized as the decimal in [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), then [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the remaining commas with a single *whitespace* in the non numerical columns.

```
df = pd.read_csv(myfile, decimal=",").replace(",", " ", regex=True)
```

​
Ouput :

```
print(df)

   region  votes  share    liste
0       1   1453  45.16      ABC
1       2   5489  54.17  BCD DEF
2       3   5486  32.00      WSE
```