# In Python, how do I create a list from a .csv file in such a way as to avoid commas inside quotations while separating using commas

Tags: python, csv, methods, list-comprehension

I'm completely stumped.  Here are the contents of my .csv file:

```
[('54th St. & Ray Rd., Chandler,"Chandler, AZ",AZ,Yes,3/29/2022,6/9/2022,72,1,9,10,17,0.5882,
-0.8000,0.1000,No')]
```

When I bring in the .csv data, I use the below method to pick out a bunch of data I want and create another list:

```
self._store_data = list()
        with open(filename, "r") as file_open:
            csvreader = csv.reader(file_open, delimiter=';')
            listed = [items for items in csvreader]
            listed.pop(0)
            print(listed)
            new_list = []
            for item in listed:
                new_list.append(item[0].split(","))
            #print(new_list)
            #print(len(new_list))
            best_list = list(map(itemgetter(0, 1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 15),
                                 new_list))
            for index, (a, b, c, d, e, f, g) in enumerate(best_list):
                best_list[index] = (str(a), str(b), str(c), str(d), int(e),
                                    int(f), str(g))
            self._store_data = best_list
```

I'm mostly able to turn it into a nice list of tuples that I then manipulate, but because I'm separating each item by "," a comma in .split(",") I'm creating extra indices that I don't want.

So the above is being turned into this:

```
['54th St. & Ray Rd.', ' Chandler', '"Chandler', ' AZ"', 'AZ', 'Yes', '3/29/2022', '6/9/2022', '72', '1', '9', '10', '17', '0.5882', '-0.8000', '0.1000', 'No']
```

See how "Chandler" got yanked out of the quoted item and now occupies it's own index, also AZ now occupies two indices, making the index total of this line 0-16 instead of 0-14.

I need to find a way to create my new list from the .csv file in such a way as to treat the entire quoted text as one string and prevent .split(",") from reaching inside.

Or, if there's some other way to do this without using .split(), very excited to learn about it from you

My code from above creates this:

```
('54th St. & Ray Rd.', ' Chandler', ' AZ"', 'AZ', 72, 1, '0.1000')
```

The first AZ was actually inside a quotation with Chandler (e.g. "Chandler, AZ"), but it got broken out with the .split(",")

Comment: If you're reading this data from a csv file, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21527057/python-parse-csv-ignoring-comma-with-double-quotes) as it might help with your problem.

Comment: If your columns are delimited by a comma, then why are you reading the CSV file with semicolon as the column delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got any results given your code uses `;` as a delimiter and then `listed.pop(0)` which should result in an empty list.
[`qoutechar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar) defaults to `'"'` with csv so try without the delimiter.

```py
from pprint import pp
import csv, io

csv_file = '''\
54th St. & Ray Rd., Chandler,"Chandler, AZ",AZ,Yes,3/29/2022,6/9/2022,72,1,9,10,17,0.5882,-0.8000,0.1000,No
'''

with io.StringIO(csv_file, newline='') as file:
    listed = [list(map(str.strip, row)) for row in csv.reader(file)]
    for row in listed: pp(row, compact=True)
```

gives a proper list:

```
['54th St. & Ray Rd.', 'Chandler', 'Chandler, AZ', 'AZ', 'Yes', '3/29/2022',
 '6/9/2022', '72', '1', '9', '10', '17', '0.5882', '-0.8000', '0.1000', 'No']
```